# show one phtml file in all subcategories page in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have One parent category and subcategories below that. when I click on any subcategory its showing products in that category but I want to change that. I want to show a PHTML page which will have 1 image and products of that category below that image. I am not getting how I can do that.

```
Category1 category2 category3---
           -----child cate 2
               -----sub cate 1
               -----sub cate 2
               -----sub cate 3
               -----sub cate 4
```

I want to call same PHTML page for all sub cate and that PHTML will show products from that

Comment: let me clarify: you just want to show something like a header/banner image above categories of certain level?

Comment: now whenever i m clicking any sub category its showing products instead of that i want to show my custom phtml page

Comment: ...but you still want to preserve layered navigation on the left? just replace the product grid with custom template?

Comment: I want this only for some categories. I am trying to call a static page in which I am calling a phtml file. but that static block is not showing on frontend it always showing products